# ArgumentError in OmniauthCallbacksController#azure_activedirectory_v2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, azure, devise, single-sign-on, omniauth

I'm using [omniauth-azure-activedirectory-v2](https://github.com/RIPGlobal/omniauth-azure-activedirectory-v2) gem for implementing Azure AD SSO through omniauth. I can sign in to my Microsoft account but receive an ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)) in the Callback controller when Azure responds to me. I made everything using instructions but that doesn't work. Maybe anyone made Azure SSO integration and can help me?

Gem versions:

```
    omniauth (1.9.1)
      hashie (>= 3.4.6)
      rack (>= 1.6.2, < 3)
    omniauth-azure-activedirectory-v2 (1.0.0)
      omniauth-oauth2 (~> 1.7)
    omniauth-oauth2 (1.7.1)
      oauth2 (~> 1.4)
      omniauth (>= 1.9, < 3)
```

OmniauthCallbacksController.rb

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def azure_activedirectory_v2
    response_params = request.env['omniauth.auth']['info']
    @user = User.find_by!(email: response_params['email'])

    if @user&.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication
    else
      flash[:alert] = @user.errors.full_messages.join('<br>')
      Rails.logger.error "Couldn't login user: " + @user.errors.inspect
      redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
    end
  end
end
```

model/user.rb

```
devise :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:azure_activedirectory_v2]
```

routes.rb

```
devise_for :users,
             path: '/auth',
             only: %i(invitations omniauth_callbacks),
             controllers: { invitations: 'invitations', omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks' },
             class_name: 'User'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get a little further.  I am using the devise gem, and can login successfully without SSL (on my development workstation).  But on our server, with Passenger Fusion, request.env['omniauth.auth']['info'] comes back nil.  More specifically, I see this in the raw HTTP:

```
"omniauth.params"=>{} 
AND
@app=#<OmniAuth::Strategies::AzureActivedirectoryV2>, 
@default_options={:path=>"/", 
  :domain=>nil, :expire_after=>nil, 
  :secure=>false, :httponly=>true, 
  :defer=>false, :renew=>false}

config/initializers/devise.rb
```

```
  config.omniauth :azure_activedirectory_v2,
                  client_id:     Rails.application.secrets['azure_client_id'],                                                              
                  client_secret: Rails.application.secrets['azure_client_secret'],                                                         
                  tenant_id:     Rails.application.secrets['azure_tenant_id'],
                  callback_path: "/users/auth/azure_activedirectory_v2/callback"
```

Would be wonderful if someone posted a working example of using this gem with SSL/Passenger/Devise.

Comment: any luck here ? seeing similar issues with just getting the omniauth hash vars to be passed to the controller